# Should I use an extension power cord instead?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I have the following Apple MacBook Pro Power adapter:

> 60W  MagSafe PV85 Ouptput 16.5v--3.65A ADP-60AD T
>
> Model No. A1344

Instead of buying a Power Adapter, is it ok to buy an [Extension power cord](http://www.ebay.com/itm/APPLE-MacBook-Pro-A1172-A1222-A1290-A1334-85W-AC-Adapters-Extension-Power-Cord-/330709429793?) (Found this on eBay)?

Will I be still be able to charge my MacBook with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Power adapter and cable]

The extension cord is the part on the right. One came with your power adapter, and it goes between the adapter and the wall. A new one would work fine with your current power adapter but won't do anything by itself.

Comment: I don't think i got a extension cord free with my macbook. So what you say is that there is no point in buying an extension cord, because i will not be able to charge my MacBook

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that the MagSafe connector at the top-left of that photo is damaged. No, the extension won't help.

Comment: Can i replace the MagSafe connector (5 Pin part) with another  ? Is there any other cheap replacement device (when compared with the Power Adapter) i could use to charge my Machine ?

Comment: No, sorry. You'll need a new power adapter.

Comment: Thanks, In my power adapter it says A1344 as its part number, but can i use any of the following part numbers `A1172, A1181, A1184, MA538LL/A, 661-0443, 661-4269, 661-4485, 661-4259, 661-4339`

Comment: There are only a few Apple adapters, so it's not hard to find the right one. If you have a 13" MacBook or MacBook Pro, you need a 60W adapter. Airs take a 45W adapter and 15/17" models take an 85W adapter. There are also variations of the 45 and 85 with MagSafe 2 connections, which are only for some of the latest models. You can also use an adapter with a different wattage, but you'll get poor performance if its wattage is lower than what the laptop requires.

Answer (score 0):

If you just change the head of the adapter there's no reason you couldn't charge your MBP.

Comment: How can i change it ? It is fixed right. Sorry i am new to this

Comment: No the head is a removable part of the adapter and you can replace it with the power cord.

Comment: Could you show me an image of the head (which you are talking about ?). the problem i have is that the 5 pin part has got corroded. Can i replace this ? Help

Comment: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41WmEIwOtgL._SL500_AA300_.jpg Here the head is removed.

Comment: The MagSafe end (the 5-pin part) is firmly attached to the power adapter and not replaceable.

Comment: So guys.. is it replaceable or not replaceable :S